# Django - Generate shortest random slug

Tags: python, django, random, unique, slug

How i can generate random slug consisting of the smallest amount of characters.
i try with this.

```
import random
import string

u_id = ''.join(random.choice(string.ascii_letters + string.digits) for _ in range(8))
```

and model

```
class Articles(models.Model):
    slug = models.CharField(max_length=6)
```

How i can do this in model? Generate slug, check if is available and set.
I want create short slugs lenght 1 to 6 chars, best for me is starting from 1 letter slugs.

Comment: have you considered using the library uuid? for example u_id = uuid.uuid4()

Comment: or even better a UUIDField ex. slug = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)

Answer (score 2):

At a basic level, you could do this:

```
import random
import string 

def rand_slug():
    return ''.join(random.choice(string.ascii_letters + string.digits) for _ in range(6))


class Articles(models.Model):
    slug = models.CharField(max_length=6, unique=True, default=rand_slug())
```

Above will generate a random slug that is 6 characters long. By using `unique=True` on your model, it will make sure no other `Article` object has that slug.

If you want to take a more advanced approach, I would recommend generating this slug in a model manager by writing your own `create` method. You can then make the random slug have a dynamic size value, character set, etc.

Comment: Note that django also has a built in random string generating function: `from django.utils.crypto import get_random_string`

Comment: And what if the rand_slug will return non-unique slug? I mean that one that is already in database.